# Capture File Stream Data in Argparse

Tags: python-3.6, argparse

I'd like to capture the help output from argparse in a string:

```
import argparse
pp = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="foo")
pp.add_argument('bundle_dir', help='Directory containing bundles',
                        default='default_val')
pp.print_help() # What this to go to a string
```

For its part argparse lets you pass a file handle to print_help:

```
def print_help(self, file=None):
        if file is None:
            file = _sys.stdout
        self._print_message(self.format_help(), file)
```

Is there anyway to create an object that will act like a file but will capture the help data so I can use it as a string?

Comment: Look at `_print_message`.  It uses `file.write(message)`.  So the `file` has to have a `write` method.  But note that `format_help` already returns a string. Have you tried using that?

Comment: I didn't know about format_help. I'll check it out.